Win11 Control Panel says my computer has these three programs installed, but where are they?
Those programs are: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.38.33135,
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.38.33135  and
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable - 10.0.30319
I assume they are C++ compilers (and if they are not, what are they?), but they're nowhere to be found. I found this article right here in StackOverflow, followed the instructions but the corresponding folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022 is empty. Also, there is no devenv anywhere under C:\Program Files.
Yet those programs can be uninstalled or repaired.
I don't have much use for a MS C++ compiler, but wouldn't mind having one - just in case, should an opportunity to use it pops up.
I have litte to report in this case. I tried to locate the executable according instructions given in a reply to a previous question but found nothing. devenv was not found. I also tried vc++ on a command window and this executable doesn't seem to either exist or be in the PATH.
Thanks.

They are not compilers, they are the runtime support dlls that VC++ programs typically need.  Files get copied into c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\syswow64.  Don't uninstall, you'll break existing programs on the machine that need those dlls.
